# Win 8.1: How to get "All Programs" menu?

Tags: windows-8.1, start-menu

Applications designed for operating systems prior to `Windows 8.1` (eg. XP, Win 7) will often create folders and shortcuts in `Programs` or `All Programs` from the `Start` menu.

How can you access these folders and shortcuts when in `Win 8.1`?

Ref: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-windows-81-arranges-tiles-for-new-desktop-prog.html

Answer (score 4):

You can right click on programs on the start screen and click on "Open File Location"

I believe shortcuts are stored in the following locations

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

`%USERNAME%` will automatically refer to whatever name you are using on your computer at the time. That is your local programs. The ProgramData would be considered All Programs

Answer (score 2):

[In Windows 8.1 it is called **All Apps**](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/where-is-all-programs-in-windows-8/02de67a4-09cd-440e-8587-a4a1ff3077cc). There are no 'folders' or 'subfolders' anymore for All Programs. You can show **All Apps** by clicking on the downwards arrow at the bottom left in the Start Screen.

An approach similar to All Programs (which shows all the programs but no subfolders) is [here](http://blog.laptopmag.com/how-to-add-an-all-programs-button-to-the-windows-8-taskbar).

Comment: The fastest way to get to the Apps screen (i.e. All Programs menu) is to use the keyboard shortcut Win to get to Start screen, and then Ctrl + Tab. Ctrl + Tab again to get back to Start screen. Use Esc to get back to last used window, Win + D to get to desktop.

Comment: @Stranger your comment seems to be THE answer.

Comment: @Stranger, Ctrl Tab is such a weird shortcut for that.

Answer (score 0):

Is actually you no need to fill it, system will fill it automatically . But need remake the username to %USERNAME%. So it will look like this.

C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs